# How to make colon of \cvitem \cvdoubleitem bold?

Tags: fonts, packages, moderncv, bold

Here's a example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in, top=0.4in]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{}{}
\phone[mobile]{}                   
\email{}
\social{}
\homepage{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
{\small
  \item[] \cvdoubleitem{\textbf{Languages}}{C, Python, Shell, Javascript}{\textbf{Frameworks}}{React, Node.js, OpenGL}
  \vspace{-3pt}
  \item[] \cvdoubleitem{\textbf{Architectures}}{MIPS/x86}{\textbf{Systems}}{Linux/UNIX, gem5}
  \vspace{-3pt}  
  \item[] \cvitem{\textbf{Tools}}{grep, gdb, Git, Emacs, LaTeX, MS Office}
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

You'll see that the content header (first argument of `\cvitem` and first two arguments of `\cvdoubleitem`), I use `\textbf{}` to bold it, but `\cvitem` and `\cvdoubleitem` add their own colon, that is not bold.

I had thought to add my own inside `\textbf{}`, that is bold, but then there would be two colons. How can I either remove theirs, or make it bold?

Here's a picture for reference:

[image]

You can see the colons aren't bold.